# ksql-test-runner throwing JMX connector server communication error

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, ksqldb

The ksql-test-runner is throwing JMX connector server communication error while running the tool.
Below is the error stack trace that am receiving.

```
sh-4.4$ ksql-test-runner -s /testing/ksql-statements-enhanced.ksql -i /testing/input.json -o /testing/output.json

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: JMX connector server communication error: service:jmx:rmi://primary-ksqldb-server:1089
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1089; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:820)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
        at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
        at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1089; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$PermanentExporter.exportObject(ConnectorBootstrap.java:203)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:153)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:138)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:473)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:816)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
        ... 12 more
```

Below is the configuration of ksqlDb server in docker-compose.yml file

```
primary-ksqldb-server:
    image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-server:${KSQL_VERSION}
    hostname: primary-ksqldb-server
    container_name: primary-ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
      - "1099:1099"
      - "1089:1089"
    logging:
      driver: local
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER : http://localhost:8088
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081, http://secondary-schema-registry:8082
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_EXTENSION_DIR: "/usr/ksqldb/ext/"
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: "nrt_"
      KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_QUERY_PULL_ENABLE_STANDBY_READS: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_HEARTBEAT_ENABLE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LAG_REPORTING_ENABLE : "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_QUERY_PULL_MAX_ALLOWED_OFFSET_LAG : 100
      KSQL_LOG4J_APPENDER_KAFKA_APPENDER: "org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender"
      KSQL_LOG4J_APPENDER_KAFKA_APPENDER_LAYOUT: "io.confluent.common.logging.log4j.StructuredJsonLayout"
      KSQL_LOG4J_APPENDER_KAFKA_APPENDER_BROKERLIST: localhost:9092
      KSQL_LOG4J_APPENDER_KAFKA_APPENDER_TOPIC: KSQL_LOG
      KSQL_LOG4J_LOGGER_IO_CONFLUENT_KSQL: INFO,kafka_appender
      KSQL_KSQL_QUERY_PULL_METRICS_ENABLED: "true"
      KSQL_JMX_OPTS: >
          -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1089
```

Enabling the JMX metrics for ksqlDB server is causing this issue. Without JMX metrics configuration, ksql-test-runner tool is working fine.

I would like to enable JMX metrics and also run ksql-test-runner tool without any issues.

Comment: What happens when you just set `JMX_PORT: 1089` and remove `KSQL_JMX_OPTS`

Comment: With this change, ksql-test-runner tool is running fine, but the JMX metrics are not working.

Comment: What tool are you trying to use to connect? Ideally, you'd use Prometheus JMX exporter agent, mounted as a volume

Comment: The problem is resolved. I am using docker containers for running ksqlDb servers. I am running this command from command line inside docker container of ksqlDb server which is causing this issue. Instead I ran the command against ksql-cli which worked fine for me. Thank you...

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred as I was running the command within the docker container of the ksqlDb server. I resolved the problem by running the command against ksql-cli instance as below.

```
docker exec ksqldb-cli ksql-test-runner -s script.sql -i input.json -o output.json
```